# Visual basic opening file dialog

Tags: vb.net

I want to open a file dialog from clicking a button however I only want it to open to a filepath that I set and for the user to only be able to edit that folder, is this possible?

Comment: so far I have been able to get it to open to a specific path but I also want it to be locked to that folder

Comment: Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
        fd.InitialDirectory = "File Path"

Comment: Try to follow the @Steve answer by using `FileOk` event an let us know

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to block your user to navigate to other directories if he/she has the permissions to go there. The `OpenFileDialog` doesn't provide any infrastructure to block to the current directory.

There is a `FolderBrowserDialog` class, but this is used only to select a folder and not to select a file.

You can set the `InitialDirectory` property before opening the dialog and check if the user selects a file in another directory using the `FileOk` event without closing the dialog

```
Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp\testpath"
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 
.......


Private Sub openFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As Object, _
       ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
       Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    Dim ofd = CType(sender, OpenFileDialog)
    if ofd.Filename <> string.Empty Then
        if Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.Filename).ToLower() <> "c:\temp\testpath" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a file only from C:\TEMP\TESTPATH folder")
            ' Just cancel the OK, not found any way to reposition the dialog on the correct folder'
            e.Cancel = true
        Endif
    End If
End Sub
```